# PowerShell не отображает кириллицу в команделете

Tags: c#, кодировка, powershell

Я использую команду отправки пуш-уведомлений сервиса ntfy в powershell, но вместо отображения русских символов на выходе я получаю вопросительные знаки "?". PowerShell последней версии,кодировка в нем utf-8. Я перепробовал множество вариантов решения, но ничего не помогло.

Сама команда:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body "Hello 123 Привет" -UseBasicParsing
```

Кроме этой команды я ничего не использую. Команда будет автоматически формироваться в консольном приложении C# и отправляться в PowerShell.

Зеленый текст message - это то, что отображается в пуш-уведомлении.

[image: Результат работы команды в PowerShell]

Обновление 1:

Ввод и выввод русских символов в переменную
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновление 2:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body "Hello 123 Привет" -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновление 3:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Hello 123 Привет") -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновление 4:
Код из Обновления 2 заработал правильно и отобразил кириллицу. Ответ с галочкой тоже оказался успешным. Вы можете использовать любую команделету на выбор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S. Работает только в PowerShell 7.2.7**

PowerShell 5.1 все также выдает непонятные символы

Comment: у вас шрифт в консоли вообще поддерживает русский язык? Обычно при таких проблемах либо charset меняют в консоли, либо шрифт

Comment: @tym32167
$adres = 'Воронеж'
$adres
Воронеж (результат команделеты $adres)
Я это вписал в powershell и все нормально работает

Comment: То есть сейчас кодировка ломается без участия C# приложения, верно?

Comment: вы делаете post запрос куда то, тот сервер ответ тоже в UTF возвращает?

Comment: @aepot
Все верно. Я пробовал вставлять команду напрямую в Powershell и через свое консольное приложение C#. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: @tym32167 Честно говоря, я только начинаю в этом разбираться. Но если использовать эту же команду в curl, то все работает нормально. Я не знаю как вставлять команды из C# в curl, поэтому хочу сделать это в PowerShell.

Comment: @aepot 
The result has not changed

Comment: зачем вставлять команды из C# в curl? Почему бы просто post запрос прямо из C# не сделать?

Comment: Не подумал об этом, спасибо за подсказку. Буду пытаться реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно получиться

```
$text = 'Hello 123 Привет'
$body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body $body -UseBasicParsing -ContentType 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: Выводится ошибка:
Invoke-RestMethod: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Hello 123 Привет'.

Comment: @kiki а теперь?

Comment: Спасибо большое тебе за помощь, Твой ответ сработал и вывел кириллицу. Но я решил еще раз попробовать использовать команду из Обновления 2 и все тоже получилось. Не понимаю почему в первый раз не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать POST запрос из кода, достаточно:

```
async Task Main()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var body = new StringContent("Hello 123 Привет", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://ntfy.sh/most", body);        
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();        
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

вывод

```
{"id":"1kWUestlQbmL","time":1666827434,"event":"message","topic":"most","message":"Hello 123 Привет"}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за уделенное мне время и подсказки @tym32167